Lee Smooth manifolds 15-8: Orientable hyper-surface implies trivial normal bundle

Suppose that $M$ is an orientable Riemannian manifold, and $S\subseteq
 M$ is an immersed or embedded submanifold with or without boundary.
Show if $S$ is an orientable hypersurface, then $S$ has a trivial
normal bundle.


Here is what I have attempted:
Fix an orthonormal basis for $T_pS$ $e_1,\dots,e_{n-1}$. Then since $S$ is orientable and a Riemannian manifold, it admits a unit normal tangent vector field $N$. Then define the map $\Phi:NS\to S\times \mathbb{R}$ by
$$p\mapsto (\pi(p), \eta_M(N_{\pi(p)}, e_1,\dots,e_{n-1}))$$
where $\pi$ is the projection from $NS$  to $N$ and $\eta_M$ is the orientation form of $M$. However, I am not sure how to show this is a diffeomorphism. Is this the right approach and if so, how can I show that $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism?

What's $\pi$? What's $\eta_M$? ...also, it's a general fact that a rank-1 vector bundle admitting a nowhere vanishing section is isomorphic to a trivial bundle, so you might cut the proof short by omitting what's essentially a reproof of that fact.

Thanks, updated. I don't think that this theorem is in Lee and I haven't heard about it. How would the nowhere vanishing section show triviality?

It's Cor. 10.20 in Lee, but the relevant version can be proved in a comment: Given a bundle $\pi\colon E \to X$ of rank 1 and a nowhere zero section $s\colon X \to E$, the map $\alpha\colon X \times \mathbb{R} \to E$, $\alpha(x, r) = r s(x)$ is a (smooth) map of vector bundles that restricts to an isomorphism in each fiber (since $s(x)$ forms a basis of the fibre over $x$ for all $x$ by assumption), so it is an isomorphism qed.

...looking at it, I do however think your map $\Phi$ also does the job, for the same reasons: it's smooth and a linear isomorphism on fibres, thus an isomorphism of bundles (although $\pi\colon N S \to S$ should be the projection, not the "local trivialization" (which term doesn't really make sense for a map of that shape)).

@BenSteffan Ah I see!  Very elegant proof. I dont quite see how I have a linear isomorphism on fiber as my map is constant over the fiber. Wouldn't this map need to map need to be bijective on the fibers?

Also I fixed the typo I meant to say projection.

Ah, right, excuse my tired brain. I guess the map should really be $p \mapsto (\pi(p), \eta_M(p, e_1, \ldots, e_{n - 1}))$ where $p, e_1, \ldots, e_{n - 1}$ is an orthonormal basis of $(T M)|_S \cong N S \oplus T S$; you then only need to check that this is smooth by extending it to a neighborhood. No need for $N$.
